# I can't push my Rails project to heroku, can't find bootstrap-sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems, bundler

When I try to push my project to Heroku I get this error:

```
-----> Deleting 3 files matching .slugignore patterns.
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-1.9.3
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Could not find bootstrap-sass-2.3.1.1 in any of the sources
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:kerbal-space-station.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:kerbal-space-station.git'
```

However my Gemfile certainly does have that and `bundle install` locally works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bootstrap-sass 2.3.1.1 was yanked: https://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrap-sass/versions

You should run:

```
bundle update bootstrap-sass
```

then commit the new Gemfile.lock and push to heroku

Comment: Jesus, I wonder why bundle update / bundle install didn't catch this.

Answer (score 1):

The last version of bootstrap-sass is 2.3.1.0, you're looking for 2.3.1.1 and it doesn't exists.

Check your gemfile and add:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to put version number you can only put

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

then do

```
bundle update
```

Comment: Version numbers protect from major patch changes, you should always use optimistic version requirements.